# Plugin stop normal function

Tags: magento2, plugin

is there a way to cancel the normal function in a Plugin and show some message?

Something like:

```
public function beforeSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode){

$variable = false;
if($variable){
  //do something and normal set triggers
}else{
  //stop set complete and show some text
}

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `throw new exception` exception method

```
 $message = __('Stop the function');
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException($message);
    return;
```

**NOTE: CODE TESTED**

Comment: thank you it works for me